# More descriptive text than NaN on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form with select boxes

Let's say you select an option from Convert From and an option from Convert To, rather than getting NaN on the result text box, I want a more descriptive text something like

"Please enter a number on the input field on the left hand side"

The same thing happens if someone inputs anything other than number on the input field. I want the same text to appear on the text field.

I cant figure out how to do that?

Comment: change the error message `text`, easy!

Comment: hmm I just added the following javascript  if (isNaN(document.querySelectorAll('.result')[0].innerHTML)){
   document.querySelectorAll('.result')[0].innerHTML = "Please enter a number in the input field and choose all the select fields from the left hand side ... "
 }  that did the trick. This has been solved

Comment: The problem was how to test for NaN. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Run an if statement before you change the text

```
if (math is NaN) //change text
else //number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(input is a number){
   display the result
}
else{
   display your custom message both in result and input textbox
}
```

You can even have a empty division tag placed below or to the left of your input text box and on error display your message in the div using

```
div.innerHTML(Your message);
```

Or else validate as soon as the user enters some value and leaves the input textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (isNaN(document.querySelectorAll('.result')[0].innerHTML))
{
document.querySelectorAll('.result')[0].innerHTML = "Please enter a number in the input field and choose all the select fields from the left hand side ... " 
}
```